# Apple Software Vendors

Tags: software

I'm trying to round up a list of all of my previous software purchases through the years, but it goes back decades. I know Paddle has a front end for consumers, and I have reached out to Fastspring for support, but what other "major" third-party vendors have there been? I vaguely recall one going out of business within the last decade or so...

Comment: Your contract is with the developer, not the reseller.

Comment: Email?  Most (all?) purchases involve an email with the invoice or receipt.

Answer (score 3):

## System Information

Use the macOS tool **System Information.app** to list your installed applications and where they were obtained from.

```
/Applications/Utilities/System Information.app
```

Select **Software > Applications** and sort by the **Obtained From** column.

Working through this list you can discover the legal entity responsible for each piece of software on your Mac.

Look for the **Signed by** entry:

```
Developer ID Application: Entity Name (Apple Identifier), Developer ID Certification Authority, Apple Root CA
```

The legal name of the entity appears after the `Developer ID Application:` prefix. The sequence of letters and numbers in brackets after the legal name is issued by Apple and uniquely identifies the entity within Apple's internal systems.

An XML format of this report can be exported for bulk analysis using other tools.

### Payment Processors

Both Fastspring and Paddle are payment processors. These organisations handle the payment processing on behalf of the software vendor or developer. Your relationship is with the software vendor or developer.

I suspect you are remembering the payment processor Kagi. Unfortunately Kagi [shut down in July 2016](https://tidbits.com/2016/08/04/kagi-shuts-down-after-falling-prey-to-fraud/) after 22 years in business.

### Mac App Store

If you purchased the software from the **Mac App Store**, your contract is with Apple. Apple does not act solely as a payment processor.

When you purchase software through the App Store or Mac App Store, your contractual relationship is with Apple and not the developer of the software.